# How to right align values of footerTemplate in kendo grid?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a kendo grid and i am using footerTemplate to find the sum of values in the grid.I have aligned the values of columns in the grid successfully.My question is how to align the values in footerTemplate
The following is the code i am using

```
{ 
    field: "covered_amount",
    width: "150px", 
    title: "Covered",
    sortable:false,
    attributes:  { style:"text-align:right;" },
    footerTemplate:"#= sum # "
},
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Define the footer template as:

```
footerTemplate: "<div style='float: right'>#= sum #</div>"
```

or:

```
footerTemplate: "<div style='text-align: right'>#= sum #</div>"
```

and you can even format it using kendo.toString, Example:

```
footerTemplate: "<div style='float: right'>#= kendo.toString(sum, 'c2') #</div>"
```

Comment: Wow That workend perfectly... Thankuu for the quick response.. @OnaBai

Comment: @OnaBai: Any way to get the third example working when you have the grid declaratively defined? I'm having issues with the kendo.toString part where the single apostrophes are causing problems:  
<table data-role="grid" data-columns="[{ 'field': 'MarketValue', 'format': '{0:C}', title: 'Market Value', footerTemplate: '#= kendo.toString((data.MarketValue) ? data.MarketValue.sum : 0, '{0:C}') #'},..."></table>
Not sure how I would escape the apostrophes around {0:C}